# Suitable Ubuntu version compatible on a Mac 11,1

Tags: system-installation, mac, macosx

Is there a Ubuntu version that works well on the Mac hardware 11,1?  Where can I find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/)

Answer (score 1):

Boot your Macintosh, click Bootcamp. it'll tell you all the process you want to know.

Ubuntu (and all its sub-DE) seems capable of utilizing all Apple's hardware, and should be able to work flawlessly.

*DE stands for Desktop Environment such as KDE, XFCE and so on.